# jQuery: Random Quotation Script Updating on User Click? document.write Troubles

Tags: jquery, html, dynamic, quotes, document.write

I'm trying to make a little dynamic quote rotator that overlays text on an image. Both JS and jQuery work fine for this. The issue is that I'd like it to update every time a button is clicked so that users don't have to refresh the page in order to see a new quote.

Is it even possible to execute a document.write after using jQuery.text(), .html(), or .append() to supply the code for the DIV? It works fine printing the actual text verbatim, but it won't execute the <script>.

If anyone has an experience or alternative suggestions that don't involve turning it into a whole big AJAX thing with PHP/MySQL, I'd be all ears. I'm not looking for anyone to write my code; just point me in the right direction. I have an overwhelming feeling that this should really be far easier than I'm making it out to be, and I know I'm missing something fundamental and simple.

Thank you for reading, and I welcome any advice one could offer.

Edit/update: I'm providing some basic code below to give you a better idea of what I mean.

```
<div id="text"></div>

<script src="quotes.js"></script>
$("#text").text('
  <script type="text/javascript">document.write(quote[Math.floor(Math.random()*5)]);&lt;/script&gt;
');
```

I'm just wanting to update #text with a random quote pulled from quotes.js. If I can get that to function, I can figure out how to have it update with jQuery.click() myself.

Comment: I've just seen your updated question. It's quite simple in this case: `$('#text').html(quote[Math.floor(Math.random()*5)]);`

Comment: And if I guess correctly, quotes.js just returns an array `quote`. There is no connection to server in every click, so there is no AJAX at all.

Comment: Oh my God, I'm a total retard. Why the heck was I trying to do the script inside it? OH MY GOD. Thank you for pointing out my idiocy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`document.write()` works only with an opened document, thus you should not use it within AJAX.

If you want to execution JavaScript, just use `eval()` or simply `$.getScript()`. That means the AJAX response should be an array (JSON), then each element could be a script, a html... then you send them to the appropriate function.

An example of a JSON response that you'll "render":

```
[
  0: {type: 'replace', target: 'div#replaceme', value: '<p>Hello!</p>'},
  1: {type: 'script', target: NULL, value: 'http://example.com/test.js'},
  2: {type: 'append', target: '#result', value: '<p>Item 11</p><p>Item 12</p>'}
]
```

Comment: Interesting... I'm gonna try this and I'll let you know how it goes. Thank you for the post. I had hoped to avoid a whole JSON/AJAX thing (though technically I guess any of this is AJAX) but I'll be giving your method a go.

Comment: ['JSON.parse()'](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/Using_native_JSON)` is recommended over `eval()`.

Comment: @jfriend00 I meant to use eval to execute a part of a "multi-part" response. E.g. `[0: {...}, 1: {...}, 2: {type: 'eval', target: NULL, value: 'alert("Dangerous")'}]`. But yes, we should avoid eval. In this case we might change to use `2: {type: 'alert', value: 'Not dangerous'}` so that we can control which function we call.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot use `document.write()` once the document is loaded.  Doing so will cause the entire document to be cleared and a new one started.  If you want to add text to a document that has already been loaded, then you can use the appropriate jQuery methods to modify existing elements or add new ones.

To help you with the exact code, we would need to see your HTML and a more complete description of exactly what you're trying to add to it.

As some examples, one can add objects to an element with the `.append()` jquery method or using the `.html()` method.

Comment: Some simplified code will be added to the original post momentarily. Thank you for replying!

Answer (score 1):

You can use jQuery's `html` or `append` method which executes the `script` if it is present in the content we pass.

Take a look at this demo

http://jsfiddle.net/ShankarSangoli/hFgE6/1/

Comment: Thank you kindly for the demo. I learned something about getting around scripts!

Answer (score 1):

If you want a DOM update action to happen after a click event, you simply have to attach a click handler to the button:

```
$('#your_button').click(function() {
  // Action
  $('#your_element').html('<p>something</p>');
});
```

See:
http://api.jquery.com/click/

Comment: Appreciate the help, sir. Thank you.